# CSS not applying in IIS6.0 but works in WAMP testing environment

Tags: css, iis, header, wamp

I have a development environment set up in Windows using WAMP.  The production environment is running Windows Server 2003 and IIS.  There are already two sites in production, I'm trying to add a third.  However, the CSS is not applying at all to the 3rd site.  Index.php and salestracker.css are both in the same directory.  Here's the header for the site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Salestracker</title>

<link href="salestracker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

As I stated, it's working fine in development environment and not applying any css in the production environment.  Here's the first entry in the CSS:

```
body {
background-color:#f3f2f0;
color:#104E8B;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the css in the page to see if it is a path issue where the page doesn't understand the location of the css file.

You can also try firing up fiddler tool to see what happens when it tries to load the css page.    Other than that, look at what is different between the dev and production environments.

Comment: When I try to navigate to the css page I get a 403.2 READ ACCESS FORBIDDEN message.  However I just checked the file permissions in IIS Manager and it 'read' is checked.  I'll try to adjust the permissions on the file directly instead of through IIS.

Comment: you won't be able to read the css page that way generally.  to do that you would need to set directory browse permissions on IIS which isn't really necessary I think.    Since it is just a small amount of css put a style tag in your page and put some basic styling there just to make sure it is respecting the css.  That will tell you if the issue is with the page not knowing what is going on or with the webserver not being able to read the file.   Also check the css file to make sure there aren't any extraneous characters or missing semi colons that are causing things to blow up.

Comment: Still no luck.  I've ensured that 'read' access is given to the Internet Guest Account in file properties and IIS Manager.  I cannot navigate from the server to localhost/salestracker/salestracker.css.  It gives me the same 403.2 error.  Fiddler also gets the 403.2 forbidden.  There are no differences between the dev and production, other than one is using WAMP and the other is IIS6.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, the style tag works when embedded directly in the document.

Comment: I found the problem.  The directory I put the site in was a subdirectory of another site.  So even though I installed it in IIS as it's own site and set the permissions accordingly, the permissions were still incorrect for the new folder in the old site.